# Opening error and log cat in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

This is a silly thing to fix but I can't open up my console windows in Eclipse. If I re-open Eclipse and change the file location they are there on display. However when I try the following:

> window > show other > error log

Nothing gets opened.

Has anyone ever experienced this before?

Comment: Shouldn't that be **log cat** ?

Comment: Its one work in my IDE but I changed it over regardless.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show your logcat view do:

```
window -> show view -> other->Android -> logcat
```

for error log

```
window -> show view -> error log or   window -> show view -> other->General -> error log
```